# Nasm - invalid CONTEXT after calling GetThreadContext

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I'm writing a PePacker for win32 and while doing so, I found out that I get an invalid `CONTEXT` out of `GetThreadContext`.

```
...
push PINFO                                    ; PROCESS_INFORMATION struct (null initialized)
push STINFO                                   ; STARTUPINFO struct (null initialized)
push 0
push 0
push CREATE_SUSPENDED
push 0
push 0
push 0
push 0
push filepointer                              ; Program file name
call [CreateProcessA]                         ; GetLastError returns 0
cmp eax, 0
jz ending

mov eax, [PINFO+4]                            ; Pinfo.hThread
push eax
call [ResumeThread]                           ; GetLastError returns 0

push 4h                                       ; PAGE_READWRITE
push 1000h                                    ; MEM_COMMIT
push 4h                                       ; sizeof(PCONTEXT)
push 0
call [VirtualAlloc]                           ; GetLastError returns 0

mov [ptrCtx], eax
mov ebx, CONTEXT_FULL
mov [eax], ebx
push eax
mov ebx, [PINFO+4] 
push ebx
call [GetThreadContext]                       ; GetLastError returns 0 but the values of the Context do not fit
cmp eax, 0
jz ending

mov ebx, [ptrCtx]
mov eax, [ebx+56]                             ; CTX.Ebx

push eax                                      ; all below for Testing purpose
push prStr                                    ; prStr = "%d\n"
call [printf]                                 ; prints 0 which is odd because CTX->Ebx should contain an address
pop ecx                                       ;
pop ecx                                       ;
...
```

The following `ReadProcessMemory` functions `GetLastError` call returns 299 which is probably caused by the Invalid `CONTEXT` entries.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Both `GetThreadContext` and `Wow64GetThreadContext` (which is the same as the former for 32-bit apps) need the thread to be suspended. You seems to resume it. Also they can't get the current thread context (for the same reason). Try resuming it after the call to `GetThreadContext`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I moved the `ResumeThread` function call behind `GetThreadContext` but the Context is still invalid. I try to translate a sample PePacker I found at the Internet, maybe it helps you when you have the C++ source code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/bMkoRDMl

Comment: If the `Pinfo.hProcess` exits before the `ReadProcessMemory` is executed, 299 errors will also occur. In addition, the `dwSize` of VirtualAlloc should be `sizeof(CONTEXT)` Precisely .

Comment: Try setting `ResumeThread` after `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT You were right about the 299 error. But now I get error 6 (invalid handle) when calling `GetLastError` after `ReadProcessMemory` . Since the handle parameter of `ReadProcessMemory` is `PINFO` I am now 100% sure that something with the `GetThreadContext` call is wrong. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change the addressing mode from `[PINFO+4]` to

```
mov ebx, [Pinfo]
mov eax, [ebx+4]
push eax
```

Both in `GetThreadContext` and `ResumeThread`.